# iOS Firebase push notifications alert

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

When my app is running in foreground and I send a notification from my web server (PHP), the iPhone does not alerts that the message arrived. I know that the message arrives because I save it on internal database and I can see it in a viewcontroller.

That's my JSON packet:

```
{
   "data": { 
       "mensagem":"msg",
       "dataEnvio":"2017-01-2016:06:58"
    },
    "content_available":true,
    "time_to_live":3600,
    "priority":"high",
    "notification":{
        "title":"new",
        "sound":"default",
        "body":"msg"
    },
    "registration_ids":["..."]
}
```

The same problem does not happens on Android.

Someone know what this is happening?

Comment: When a notification is sent and the app is in the foreground then the notification  is delivered to the app, not to the user, if you want the user to see it then your app must display a local notification. Incidentally, you have a payload which is not permitted according to the Apple documentation - you have content_available set to true indicating the push is an app-directed push, but it also has a notification section indicating it is a user push. Thus your payload is contradictory. This is not supposed to occur, though I don't know if Firebase do anything to the content in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The 'content_available' was wrong indeed. I removed the 'content_available' from the payload and this solved another problem I was facing. I will try to find some way to display a local notification. Again, thank you very much, it helped a lot!

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in the foreground the notification portion of the push notification is neglected in both android and ios. I am sure that you are creating the push notification yourself in android on the handling function OnMessageReceived so that it appear when you are foreground.